# Extracting file path from filebeat into logstash and then into elastic index

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat, logstash-file

I'm trying to take a part of my path and give it as index to my elasticsearch index.

my logstash config file looks like this (Note: the config file might be wrong cuz I tried 100 different things)

```
# The # character at the beginning of a line indicates a comment. Use
# comments to describe your configuration.
input {
    beats {
            port => "5044"
        }
}
# The filter part of this file is commented out to indicate that it is
# optional.
filter {
  grok {
      match => ["[log][file][path]", "c:\\PL_Logs\\%{GREEDYDATA:index_name}\\%{GREEDYDATA}" ]
  }
}
#output {
# stdout { codec => rubydebug }
#}
output {
   elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9222" ]
        index => "%{index_name}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
   }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

my logs are filed like this `C:\Incoming_Logs\requested_part\somesubfolder_doesnt_matter\2022\03\18\2022031814.txt`

my filebeat config is this:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - c:\Incoming_Logs\**\*.txt
```

My question is how can I take the `requested_part` part from my path and make it an index?
I've tried many things like covering the index with [] (%[{index_name}]) I tried to match with "path" instead of "[log][file][path]" I've changed the grok condition to "c:\PL_Logs\%{GREEDYDATA:index_name}\**" and I've also tried to use "/" instead of double "\"

Can someone point me out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the grok match that works for me from this question [How to get parts of Filebeat source filename in Logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59358382/how-to-get-parts-of-filebeat-source-filename-in-logstash)

I made mine like this
 `match => { "[log][file][path]" => ".*(\\|\/)(?<myIndex>.*)(\\|\/).*.*(\\|\/).*(\\|\/).*(\\|\/).*(\\|\/)" }`

It works but I prefer a more elegance regex if someone can help.